# Typoscript Menu: if "directory" list is empty then use "entrylevel"

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I use the Special Menu element "Menu of sub pages of selected pages". 
I would like to modify it so that it shows a sitemap of the sub pages of the current page if there are no entry pages defined - otherwise it should work as usually.

I've tried to overwrite the element like this - but I have no idea how to do the condition for changing from directory to entrylevel.

```
menu.sub < menu.template // A standard TMENU template
menu.sub {
    special = directory
    special.value.field = pages
    #entryLevel= -1 ***USE THIS IF THE special value ABOVE IS EMPTY***
    1.expAll = 1
    1.wrap = <ul class="subnav">|</ul>
    2.expAll = 1
    2.wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    3 < .2
}
tt_content.menu.20.1 < menu.sub
```

Comment: Could you please also provide the TS code for "menu.template" to get the bigger/ complete picture? Right now, I think you've got a problem with conflicting settings. If you want to use "entryLevel" then you have to reset the "special" settings.

Comment: @Björn: you are right that both settings (entrylevel + directory) would conflict. My question is how to add a condition to use either one or the other. Regarding TMENU template you could use this one: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptIn45MinutesTutorial/CreateAMenu/Index.html

Comment: Thx for your answer. Acoording to the documentation, .special and .entryLevel cannot be combined (see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/ContentObjects/Hmenu/#the-special-property). Furthermore, the documentation (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/ContentObjects/Hmenu/#special-directory) says if you do not provide (a valid) uid the special.directory function does use the uid of the current page. This should be the expected behaviour. Which TYPO3 version do you use?